# MVC How to call an action in controller from view to return a value

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, view

I am working on an mvc project. In a Home controller i have an action which is called GetCityByID which takes id and checks the db for a city and returns city name.

In My View, I want to call this action and get a result and display it.

Can someone please demonstrate different ways of doing this?

i think i could through ajax/javascript, also through @url.Action ?

Comment: Also check out the `Html.RenderAction()` and `Html.RenderPartial()` methods

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make `ajax` call to controller method from view. Following will be the JS code.

```
$.ajax({
async: false,
cache: false,
type: "GET",
url: "@(Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController"))",
data: { "id": ui.item.Id }, //Param
success: function (data) {
}
});
```

MVC code in controller.

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
   public JsonResult ActionName(int id)
   {
       ....Your Code....
       return Json(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In View :
    $.ajax({
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: "@(Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController"))",
    data: { "id": ui.item.Id }, //Param
    success: function (data) {
    }
    });

MVC Controller Code:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult ddlSurgeryDescription(string id)
{
          Do Process Here 

return Json(new { id = ViewData["ddlSurgeryDescription"] }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 

}
```